# How to hang hard to hang picture

Tags: hanging

I have a picture frame where the wood is narrow, maybe 1/4 inch. The backing board has sawtooths near the top.

If I hang by sawtooth it seems I’ll be hanging on nails, not hooks (most hooks I see don’t stick out as much as the nails). I have toddlers, this doesn’t seem safe around them.  If they were teens and I could expect them to ignore it I’d do this way.

I wanted to get clips to clip to the side of the backing board, then wire across those. Those seem hard to come by. Maybe for a reason?  I’ve seen them as mostly stable though a little bit of shift.

Every kit I see has D rings. To me I’m worried about splitting the wood. Again, very narrow frame.

So, are there clips I can get (I have an ikea frame that I used this on) or do they slide too much?  Is there some other option to hang these, non sawtooth non D-ring and wire, that I’m missing?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you immagine your toddlers interacting with this picture?

Comment: @Jasen it’s above the couch. They’re pretty smart about intentionally disregarding things we tell them to disregard, but it’s not hard to accidentally bump

Comment: Ide some deep hooks out of stiff wire  this means the picture needs to be lifted higher before it disengaces from the hook than id just a bare nail was used.

Answer (score 1):

I would hang the frames on nails or screws with suitable heads, and then secure the frames at the bottom using double stick tape or poster putty. This will prevent them from being inadvertently lifted or bumped off the anchors.

I have found that drywall nails have the right combination of size and a wide thin head for this purpose. if you need to use hollow wall anchors, some drywall screws have a head with enough of a flange that they might work well.

Comment: I pretty much did this. Screws for real support and some 3M Command to keep from shifting.